# How to configure unique column name in Entity class using MongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I want to save email id for username in MongoDB so that always should be unique.

When we use Spring Data Jpa then we write as below in Entity class:

```
@NotNull
@Column(name = "email_id", length = 55, **unique=true**)
private String emailId;
```

But in case of MongoDB how I configure this scenario in entity class. Is there any extra annotation given by Spring?

I am using Spring Data MongoDB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe in order to properly use Spring with MongoDB you need to use Spring Mongodb:

https://projects.spring.io/spring-data-mongodb/

In that case your @entity becomes a @document and your @column becomes a @field and to make something unique you mark the field as @Indexed(unique=true)